# Completely filling polygons with text labels on per-feature basis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, arcgis-pro

I would like to create a **map of regions, where each region is completely filled with its specific chunks of text**. Think a map of [Wordles](http://www.wordle.net) in the shape of regions that are assembled together into a map.

[image]

This is [an example (not mine) for the UK](http://livinggeography.blogspot.ch/2011/04/tagxedo-seaside-descriptions-ukcside.html) but where all UK is one region instead of divided into counties.

[image]

Either approach – web map (using e.g. D3 or cartodb) or traditional offline map (made e.g. in QGIS) – would be fine.

I suspect this is actually quite a hard problem (fitting text inside polygon, collision detection, automatic placement, ...).

Comment: So each feature should be filled using a different set of words?

Comment: I very much doubt you are going to find a auto solution for this. Most of those maps would be made in non-GIS tools.

Comment: As already mentioned, this has been done outside of a GIS. In fact, the map you link to was made using this http://www.tagxedo.com/

Comment: @Jake: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @NathanW: Yes, I can imagine it could be really hard in a desktop GIS, but figured it oughta be doable in e.g. Processing or D3?

Comment: @Dan_h_b: True, and I checked out Tagxedo. But it offers only some standard shapes. Even if I could find a tool that let's me use custom shapes, I'd need to come up with an approach to re-assemble them into a map and would still end up with potentially not high-quality raster graphics.

Answer (score 1):

A way forward with this using ArcGIS for Desktop, or more likely ArcGIS Pro, may be to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).

Also, if [Ask A Cartographer](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/01/25/the-new-face-of-ask-a-cartographer/) is still around then that might be a good place to set this as a challenge.